# Find the point on a plane $3x + 4y + z = 1$ that is closest to $(1,0,1)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Is anyone able to help me with regards to this question?

Find the point on a plane $3x + 4y + z = 1$ that is closest to $(1,0,1)$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaFG0.png

Comment: Find the equation for a normal to the plane, the normal passing through the given point defines the point you are looking for.

Comment: Compute the distance from $(x, y, z)$ to the given point. Adding the restriction that $(x, y, z)$ lies on the plane (use Lagrange multipliers) gives you the point.

Comment: Here’s another method. Parameterize the plane as follows. Choose two non-parallel vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ in the plane (perpendicular to $\vec{n}=(3,4,1)$), say $(-1,0,3)$ and $(0,-1,4)$, and a point $P$ in the plane, say $(0,0,1)$. An equation for the plane is then $\{P+s\vec{a}+t\vec{b}:s,t\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{(3s-t,4s,s+3t+1):s,t\in\mathbb{R}\}$. With calculus, find $s_0,t_0$ that minimize the distance squared from $(3s-t,4s,s+3t+1)$ to $(1,0,1)$: $d(s,t)=(3s-t-1)^2+(4s)^2+(s+3t+1)^2$. (This minimizes the distance, but is easier.) The closest point is then $(3s_0-t_0,4s_0,s_0+3t_0+1)$.

Answer (score 13):

The normal vector to the plane is $\langle 3,4,1\rangle$. The point you seek would have to be some multiple of this vector added to $(1,0,1)$. $$P=(1,0,1)+c\langle 3,4,1\rangle=(1+3c,4c,1+c)$$ 
But this point has to satisfy the plane's equation:
$$\begin{align}
3(1+3c)+4(4c)+(1+c)&=1\\
26c+4&=1\\
c&=-\frac{3}{26}
\end{align}$$

So $$P=(1,0,1)-\frac{3}{26}\langle 3,4,1\rangle=\left(\frac{17}{26},-\frac{12}{26},\frac{23}{26}\right)$$

Comment: Would you by chance know why the point would lie on the line $P=(1,0,1)+c(3,4,1)?$

Comment: @user135520, ik this is years old now. But it's because the normal points directly towards the plane. Meaning that going from your point (1, 0, 1) along the normal is the shortest path to the plane.

Answer (score 3):

With Lagrange Multipliers, we have the distance function $f(x,y,z)=(x-1)^2+y^2+(z-1)^2$ (squaring to simplify the calculations) and the constraint $3x+4y+z=1$. We get $$(x-1,y,z-1)=\lambda(3,4,1)$$ Therefore $$(x-1)/3=(y/4)=(z-1/1)=\lambda$$ and as the user above stated this gives the closest point.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is a multivariable minimization problem in which you want to minimize some function f(x,y,z) subject to the constraint g(x,y,z) - c = 0.

The first thing to understand is that the function you are minimizing is the distance from the point (1,0,1).

$$
f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y^2)+(z-1)^2}
$$

and your constraint is

$$
3x+4y+z-1 = 0
$$

From here you can use the standard Lagrange Multipliers method. The wikipedia intro section here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier covers this nicely.

One last tip: minimizing the square of the distance function will give the same result, and is much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x, y, z)$ be the point in question. The distance is given by $\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + y^2 + (z - 1)^2}$. By Cauchy Schwarz, $\left((x-1)^2 + y^2 + (z-1)^2\right)(3^2 + 4^2 + 1^2) \geq (3x + 4y + z - 4)^2$, so $\left((x-1)^2 + y^2 + (z-1)^2 \right) \geq \frac{9}{26}$

Equality is reached when $\frac{x-1}{3} = \frac{y}{4} = \frac{z-1}{1}$. Solving using $3x + 4y + z = 1$ gives $\left(\frac{17}{26}, -\frac{6}{13}, \frac{23}{26} \right)$

Comment: What hat does the $3^2 + 4^2 + 1^2$ rabbit come from?

Comment: I used that so I could get the desired coefficients of $3, 4, 1$ on $x, y, z$ so I could substitute the fact that $3x + 4y + z = 1$. Is there something wrong with the solution?

Comment: No, just that it is missing an explanation.

Comment: Well there it is. Wanted the coefficients to be equal to what we have in the line equation.

Answer (score 0):

For the completeness of discussion, I would give an approach using multivariable calculus but without Lagrange Multiplier.

The square of the distance between any point $(x,y,z)$ and $(1,0,1)$ is given by:

$$
d^2=(x-1)^2+y^2+(z-1)^2 \tag{1}
$$

Sub. $z=1-3x-4y$ into eq. (1) and define a function $f(x,y)$ as follows:

$$
f(x,y):=(x-1)^2+y^2+(1-3x-4y-1)^2
$$

$$
f(x,y)=(x-1)^2+y^2+(3x+4y)^2
$$

$f(x,y)$ can be interpreted as the square of the distance between points on the plane and the point $(1,0,1)$.  Our objective is to find a local minimum point of $f(x,y)$ if exists. As $f(x,y)$ is minimized, $d$ will be minimized.  As such, we calculate the gradient and Hessian matrix of $f$ as follows:

$$
\nabla f(x,y)=
\begin{bmatrix}
2(x-1)+2\cdot3(3x+4y) \\
2y+2\cdot4(3x+4y)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\nabla f(x,y)=
\begin{bmatrix}
20x + 24y - 2 \\
24x+34y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
H=
\begin{bmatrix}
20 & 24 \\
24 & 34
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The Hessian is always $104>0$.

$$
\nabla f(x,y)=\mathbf{0}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
20x + 24y - 2 \\
24x+34y
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

By solving the above system of linear equations, we obtain $x=17/26$ and $y=-6/13$ as well as $z=3/2$.   As $\det (H)=104>0$ and $f_{xx}=20>0$, thus $(17/26, -6/13)$ is a local minimum of $f(x,y)$.